# How to add Json data for Header and body for bootstrapTable using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, bootstrap-table

I am using latest bootstrap-Table for Table with Dynamic data from JSON url.
I tried with static header  and TD fields [(jsfiddle-1)](https://jsfiddle.net/jsjqfinder/hp2b7g4o/10/) from JSON from bootstrap-Table also I used data-field option in th [(jsfiddle-2)](https://jsfiddle.net/jsjqfinder/bLw4zhja/7/) but What I am looking is Dynamic Header and Dynamic TD from URL using foreach. I checked with bootstrap-Table samples but not available. Please share the samples and ideas.

Fiddle 1 :

```
$(function() {

$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    url: 'https://examples.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data',
    pagination: true,
    height: 450,
    locale: 'en-US',
    pageList: [30,55,80,100],
    pageSize: 30,
    columns: [
      [ {
        title: 'Site ID',
        field: 'id',          
        align: 'center',
        valign: 'middle',
        sortable: true,
        
      } ,
      {
        field: 'name',
        title: 'Customer Name',
        sortable: true,
        
        align: 'center'
      }, {
        field: 'price',
        title: 'Depot',
        sortable: true,
        align: 'center',
      
      } ]
    ]
```

});
});

Fiddle 2:

```
$(function() {

$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    url: 'https://examples.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data',
    pagination: true,
    height: 450,
    locale: 'en-US',
    pageList: [30,55,80,100],
    pageSize: 30
```

});
});

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have dynamic header and maybe footer too, you can also try php for this situation.

Comment: Thanks for Quick reply.  I looking for JavaScript with https://bootstrap-table.com/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).